# how to change behaviour back button in android

Tags: android, back-button, onbackpressed, back-button-control

My app includes `tts` and `stt`. My app works by voice command.

So, I want to use the `back button`. When the user `click back button`, the app should go to the first step, but it didn't.

My code;

```
public class SpeechActivity extends FragmentActivity implements Const {

    protected PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock; 
    private SpeechRecognizer mSpeechRecognizer; 
    private Intent mSpeechRecognizerIntent;
    private SpeechRecognitionListener srListener;
    private Vocalizer vocalizer;
    private Object lastTtsContext = null;
.......
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        speakToDisabled(Const.COMMAND_WARNING_MESSAGE); 
        super.onBackPressed();
        try {
            mSpeechRecognizer.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            speakToDisabled(Const.COMMAND_BYE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, please be specific and more detailed in what problem you face?

Comment: Edit your code properly, and explain what exactly you want the back button to do, go to the first activity, or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete or comment this line, because it finish your current activity.

```
super.onBackPressed();
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling `super.onBackPressed()` finishes your Activity, so if you want to make your "first step" inside this Activity, comment this line.

Comment: Thank you, when delete super.onBackPressed(), I solved the my problem.